# Mysql/Php query grouping filter result

Tags: php, mysql

Really struggling figuring out the best way to code the following.  My query will generate the following results :

```
ID      OPTIONvalue     ANSWER
57      23              7
58      23              8
59      24              1
60      25              5
```

My aim will be to generate JSON something like this, I need

```
// everything here will be answers for OPTIONvalue = 23
[{
  "name": "person_name",
  "answer": 7,
  "answer1": 8
}, 

// everything here will be answers for OPTIONvalue = 24
[{
  "name": "person_name",
  "answer": 1,
},
```

Currently, I query the database to get all the optionvalues, then loop these results so I can do  where OPTIONvalue =23 in mysql select.  this is querying the database about 15 times… its obviously a terrible idea, but I cant figure out what I should be doing to code it better.

I have tried to simplify what I am asking, I hope you understand, if not let me know so I can edit the above.

Comment: your json is impossible. you cannot have two different lines with the same key. it's not an error, but the last key in the sequence will overwrite/replace the values from all the other previous identical keys.

Comment: thanks, the JSON was a typo i edited. My question is more how to avoid multiple queries to the database.

Comment: use an sql `join` and just fetch all the records at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try

```
SELECT OptionValue,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Answer ORDER BY Answer) Answers
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY OptionValue
```

That will yield one row per OptionValue, with a comma-separated list of Answer values. It should be straightforward to convert that to JSON.

Comment: Interesting, looks like this maybe what i need. Thanks, will look into it and update / accept answer.

Comment: Right. Aggregate (`GROUP BY`) functions are very useful. Worth learning about.

Comment: Yep, will do some research into it now, this is exactly what i needed - I have it working in phpmyadmin. Thanks!